# Make 'Read More' button in tableview cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview

I have a simple Tableview which has dynamic cells.

Each cell has  3 elements ( **question as UILabel** - **Answer as UITextView** - **readmore as UIButton** )

I just need to show 2 lines from the Answer in every cell and when I click read more button the height of the cell should dynamically change depending on the answer textview characters.

And here's my calling table cell Method :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            tableCell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("fqaCell") as! fqaTableViewCell
             myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 100
            myTable.rowHeight = 100





            return tableCell!
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this first of all initialise rowHeight to UITableViewAutomticDimension and estimatedRowHeight  to 100 (according to your code) in viewDidLoad method. This will help to resize the cell according to its contents. Now if you want to display entire text of lable then set lable's numberOfLine  to 0, otherwise 2.To achieve this  maintain a dictionary or array to store bool status all the cell's read more button. Toggle its value when button is clicked and then reaload tableview or reload corresponding cell. Hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't call `rowHeight` from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method since this will get called for each cell and apply for all of the cells in the table view.

Use the methods `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` to configure individual cells instead.

Secondly, you should show some effort for what you've tried this far, but I guess trying out these methods gives you a hint at how to accomplish what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all set height constraint to the textview say is => 80

and also limit the count of answer string while setting it to textView.. so that on reading more we can get actual full-length answer.. drag the height constraint to the table view cell.. and on read more button click do this

```
//code
@IBAction func readMoreBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AnswersCell
        if(cell.answerTextView.text.count < answerList[sender.tag].answer.count){


            cell.answerHeightConstraints.isActive = false

            tableView.beginUpdates()
            cell.answerTextView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:cell.answerTextView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80))


       cell.answerTextView.text = alertsFeedList[sender.tag].answer

            cell.readMoreBtnOfCell.isHidden = true
            tableView.endUpdates()


        }
```

You got to drag the button to cell as outlet and in table view as action. In `cellForRowAt` do this  `cell.readMoreBtnOfCell.tag = indexPath.row`

Comment: tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() did the trick thanks